# How to overlay audio streams on each other

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I have a bunch of audio streams, i want to overlay them all on each other and make one final stream audio stream. [This is how it would look visually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lhet.png)

So in the final stream, it would be like all of the previous audio streams are playing together. How may i accomplish this?

Comment: ffmpeg is great for audio/video processing stuff.

Comment: would it work for live audio streams?

Comment: Works afaik only with files on the fs or with one input stream over stdin. But feel free to search for "multimedia frameworks" There are more than enough solutions to work with multimedia data. One of them can handle multiple input streams (mux/demux as keywords) Another solution could be to work with fifo/named pipes as input files and write the stream data there. `ffmepg -i ./pipe1 -i ./pipe2 -i ./pipeN` etc. pp. Quick search: https://localcoder.org/multiple-named-pipes-in-ffmpeg perhaps there is something useful for you in it.

Comment: Found some strange attempt with multiple input pipes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72176714/5781499 Perhaps you can do the same