# Merge video and audio using ffmpeg in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, ffmpeg, encoding, ytdl

I am using **FFmpeg-static** in my Express server to merge audio and video coming from Youtube Readable Stream. I have found one code on one Github repo but that code is converting and saving directly to the **backend root folder**. What I want is to merge and then **pipe** it directly to the end user.
The code which I found is below:

```js
router.get('/try', async (req, res)=>{
let vid = ytdl(ytvideoUrl, {filter: format => format.qualityLabel === '144p'})
let aud = ytdl(ytvideoUrl, { quality: 'lowestaudio' })

const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
    '-loglevel', '8', '-hide_banner',
    '-progress', 'pipe:3',
    '-i', 'pipe:4',
    '-i', 'pipe:5',
    '-map', '0:a',
    '-map', '1:v',
    '-c:v', 'copy',
    `videoTitle.mp4`,
  ], {
    windowsHide: true,
    stdio: [
      'inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit',
      'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
    ],
  })
ffmpegProcess.on('close', () => {
console.log("Merging Completed");
})
  
aud.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
vid.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[5]);
})
```

Dependencies are:

```js
const cp = require('child_process');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');
```

Comment: Replace `videoTitle.mp4` with an output pipe (like you have with the input) and specify the streaming container format with `-f` option (right before the output pipe argument)

Comment: I have added `'-f', 'pipe:1',` but it didn't work.
  Error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pipe')`

Comment: Where did you get the information that you can specify multiple input streams over pipes? `-i pipe:4` & `-i pipe:5`?

Comment: I don't know how to work with FFmpeg, I have just copied the code, provided above.

Comment: I think you need to review how to use `cp.spawn.` The error is indicating that the pipe is not opened.

Comment: @Marc - FFmpeg can use multiple pipes [see doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe). Nonstandard pipes however may not be available in Windows (e.g., I cannot use it in Python or Node.js)

Comment: The node.js pipes are not "real" pipes: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio What im missing in your question is whats not working/a error message, you just posted a bunch of code but no what you expect and what in your code dosnt work.

Comment: @Marc When I run this js code through express route, the code downloads that file to my Local Host Folder and what I want to send that merged file to the user's response and then, the user can download that file.

Comment: And whats not working?

Comment: @Marc I am saying that I want to make changes in the code so that it can send the output (merged) video file directly to the user who is sending the request to the route. But currently, the code is merging the youtube video and downloading it to the server's folder (for example d:/ExpressServer/"Merged File")

Comment: I see no http/route handling in the code, Post the full code.

Comment: @Marc now check. it was just `router.get( '/try', async (req, res) =>{ **above code** })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244673/discussion-between-marc-and-muhammad-tahir-ali).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const app = express();
const cp = require('child_process');
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');
const fs = require('fs')
const readline =require('readline')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "\\static"));
app.use('/static', express.static('./static'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("It Works!");
});

app.get('/download', async (req, res) => {
    var url = req.query.url;


    res.header("Content-Disposition", `attachment;  filename=video.mp4`)
    let video = ytdl(url, {
        filter: 'videoonly'
    })
    let audio = ytdl(url, {
        filter: 'audioonly',
        highWaterMark: 1 << 25
    });
    const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
        '-i', `pipe:3`,
        '-i', `pipe:4`,
        '-map', '0:v',
        '-map', '1:a',
        '-c:v', 'copy',
        '-c:a', 'libmp3lame',
        '-crf', '27',
        '-preset', 'veryfast',
        '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
        '-f', 'mp4',
        '-loglevel', 'error',
        '-'
    ], {
        stdio: [
            'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
        ],
    });

    video.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[3]);
    audio.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
    ffmpegProcess.stdio[1].pipe(res);

    let ffmpegLogs = ''

    ffmpegProcess.stdio[2].on(
        'data',
        (chunk) => {
            ffmpegLogs += chunk.toString()
        }
    )

    ffmpegProcess.on(
        'exit',
        (exitCode) => {
            if (exitCode === 1) {
                console.error(ffmpegLogs)
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).